# how $a+_m(b+_mc)=a+_m(b+c)$?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to show that the set of first m non-negative integers is a group under the composition of addition modulo $m$. I need some help understanding this step -

$$a+_m(b+_mc)=a+_m(b+c)$$

It is given that this step follows as $b+_mc\equiv b+c(mod m) $*

Comment: What is it about that step that gives you trouble?

Comment: How does &b+_mc\equiv b+c(mod m)& implies that $(b+_mc)=b+c$

Comment: It does not. The idea, however, is that once you then further do an addition mod $m$ afterwards, the difference disappears.

Comment: It looks as if there is a text being used, and that it implicitly or explicitly defines a function on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ with values in $\{0,1,\cdots,m-1\}$, $(i,j)\mapsto$ the representative of $i+j$ modulo $m$.

Answer (score 1):

The "hint" you are given follows by *definition of addition, modulo $m$*:

$$b+_mc\equiv b+c \pmod  m $$

That is, there is a unique $q, r \in \mathbb Z\;$ such that $$b +_m c = r$$ where  $(b + c) = qm + r,\; \;0 \leq r\lt m$. Alternatively, $$b + c = r \pmod m$$

The "proof" you need follows from the above.